# Is it possible to have a tab which consist of multiple types. (single icon, and text) with jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose

I am trying to create a tab which has:

- just an icon at the start and just text at the right

[Click to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p6Euh.png)

I am using this:

**TabItem.kt**

```
sealed class TabItem(
val index: Int,
@DrawableRes val icon: Int?,
@StringRes val title: Int,
val screenToLoad: @Composable () -> Unit
){

object Camera: TabItem(0, R.drawable.ic_camera, R.string.empty_string, {
    CameraScreen()
})

object Chat: TabItem(1, null, R.string.chats, {
    ChatScreen()
})

object Status: TabItem(2, null, R.string.status, {
    StatusScreen()
})

object Call: TabItem(3, null, R.string.calls, {
    CallsScreen()
})

}
```

**UI**

```
TabRow(
    selectedTabIndex = selectedIndex,
) {

    tabs.forEachIndexed{index, tabItem ->

        Tab(
            selected = index == selectedIndex,
            modifier = modifier.background(MaterialTheme.colors.primary),
            onClick = {
            onPageSelected(tabItem)
        },

            icon = {
                tabItem.icon?.let { painterResource(id = it) }?.let { Icon(painter = it, contentDescription = stringResource(id = R.string.icon)) }
            },

            text = {
            Text(text = stringResource(id = tabItem.title))

        },)
    }
}
```

The problem is:

The icon is leaving a space for the text below..

I only need the icon in the tab along with text for other tabs..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed it like this:

```
TabRow(selectedTabIndex = 0) {
        Tab(
            selected = true,
            onClick = { },
            text = { Icon(Icons.Filled.AccountCircle, "icon", tint = Color.White).toString() })
        Tab(
            selected = true,
            onClick = { },
            text = {
                Text(text = "Text")
            })
    }
```

Comment: Sadly, It's the same, still a large space at the bottom of the icon. (just like what I showed in the image)

Comment: Hmm, that is strange: there was no space when I tried it on my emulator...

Comment: I actually added a:

Tab first:

Tab(
            modifier = modifier,
            selected = true,
            onClick = {
            },
            text = { Icon(Icons.Filled.AccountCircle, "icon", tint = Color.White).toString()
            })

Then, my tabs.forEachIndexed{ }

Comment: thanks...I found a way to bring that inside the loop and it works now.

Comment: Brilliant, well done! :-)